# DrRacket REPL not returning the cursor

Tags: racket

[image: Image of my Drracket]

I am using Dr Racket for racket programming. I am a newbie.

I have run into this problem where when I type anything on the REPL, lets say:

```
> (define a 7)
```

The cursor never returns.

If I define this in the editor

```
(define a 7)
```

And in the REPL I do

```
> a
```

The cursor never returns.

I do have `#lang racket` at the very top in the editor window.

It was working just fine for some time and then it suddenly stopped working.

Can you help?

Comment: If you close and reopen DrRacket, does the same error occur?Could I see a screenshot of your DrRacket?

Comment: @SimplyPanda If I close and open yes the same error occurs. I will attach a screen shot. The screenshot is now attached.

Comment: I think it's something wrong with the installation. I remember i had to clear cache to get something to work for me once and I would have tried a clean install, perhaps even an older version, to see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old bug that sometimes appears on Ubuntu, no one has yet figured out why.
On relevant problem report: http://bugs.racket-lang.org/query/?cmd=view&pr=12640
I find it much less frequent these days though.

Meanwhile, I've found that if the pointer doesn't return, you can type other things like `'a` or `1.1` followed by `Enter`, and it should evaluate both expressions at once and return the pointer. Note that the particular case that you give does not occur on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define a 7)
```

should not be printing anything. It is merely binds `a` to be `7`. Try typing `a` into REPL after and see what you get.

See [Racket's documentation on define](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html) for further info.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped. I corrected the question. The problem still exists.